# Red and Bold Text in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to make this text red ad bold "English" How can I do this in HTML? If there is no way to do this CSS would be still OK.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When writing a question, please show that you have tried to get things working and that you have done some research before posting. It becomes much easier to help when there is a specific problem that needs to be solved, rather than "Can someone please help me with X?"

Comment: Also, no, you can't do it with HTML. HTML is the document content, CSS is what styles the content. You can, however, make the text bold using <b> elements.

Comment: These are pretty simple problems which you can just google. “How to text red in html” “how to make text bold in html”. Try to google first before asking but when the problem is very hard thats when you post a question. Have a good day

Comment: Some answers here are recommending using the b or strong tags. Please be aware that these have different significances and are not the correct way to embolden text if that is what is required. Emboldening text as such is done through CSS not HTML. Read about the differences on MDN - for example [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do it like this in HTML with some CSS styling:

```html
<b style='color:red;'>English</b>
```

Comment: You use text-align: center;  if you want it at the center of the page, center: left; if you want it to the left etc.. Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.ASP

Comment: @OrionKnight You should use `strong` tag instead of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<b>` tag with custom styling as Below.

```html
<b style="color:red;">English</b>
```

---

Alternatively, you can use Font Weight CSS Property, to make text bold.

```html
<span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">English</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strong tag as well for achieving same result.

```html
<strong style="color:red">English</strong>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS instead of inline styling is a better way,
You can also try using "strong" tags:

```html
<strong style="color:red;">English</strong>
```